# Why is my nginx looking for a weirdly named conf file?

Tags: raspberry-pi, nginx, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi running raspbian (debian 9.3), with no problem until tonight. I use nginx to serve https sites and I needed to update my certificate with certbot so I stopped nginx. But when I started it again, this is what I got :

```
pi@framboise3:~ $ sudo service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
pi@framboise3:~ $ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-01-31 21:34:49 UTC; 10s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 1791 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

janv. 31 21:34:49 framboise3 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
janv. 31 21:34:49 framboise3 nginx[1791]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx+ngijx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
janv. 31 21:34:49 framboise3 nginx[1791]: nginx: conbiguration file /etc/nginx+ngijx.conf test failed
janv. 31 21:34:49 framboise3 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
janv. 31 21:34:49 framboise3 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
janv. 31 21:34:49 framboise3 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
janv. 31 21:34:49 framboise3 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Please notice two very strange items : the word "**conbiguration file**" and the file "**/etc/nginx+ngijx.conf**" which looks a bit like the expected /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. Of course the one mentioned does not exist.

What the hell can be happening ?

apt-get remove and install nginx didn't solve the problem. I found no occurrence of the string 'ngijx' in /etc nor /var/lib/nginx/ (don't know if it's relevant).

Other than that I noticed nothing wrong with the system. I was told it might be a defective SD card, but then why would reinstalling the package not fix the problem ? Can I test if my card is defective ? Thanks

Comment: Who told you that? Using your usual filesystem check utilities should also check for a defect. Depending your filesystem it might be more or less noticeable. Did you check what sources you have configured? Maybe one of them was compromised (though unlikely). Depending on how you removed the package there might've been faulty configuration left over.

Comment: The one who told me that is the user who told me this post did not belong to the "server fault" site :) The filesystem is ext4. My sources are basic : "deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi". And yes I left the configuration in place, but removing it changes nothing. I just solved the problem, see below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for details when replying to Seth I went a bit further and solved the problem. First I noticed this:

```
pi@framboise3:/etc $ strings /usr/sbin/nginx |grep ngij
/etc/nginx+ngijx.conf
```

Which means that this file (ELF 32-bit executable) is somehow corrupted.

Then I ran :

```
pi@framboise3:/etc $  dpkg -S /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx-full: /usr/sbin/nginx
```

And understood that reinstalling "nginx" was not the right package. Reinstalling nginx-full did the trick.
Still how it got corrupted is a mystery, and I think I'll double check my backup system...